Is there anything similar to --bind-to none in salloc
I have run the hybrid mpi/openmp code
mpirun --bind-to none -np 1 ./test

Now, I move to a cluster, where I shall use salloc in slurm.
Is there anything similar to --bind-to none in salloc ?

how will you start your app under SLURM? e.g. will you keep using mpirun or will you move to srun (aka direct run)?

I was using the command "salloc -p compute-grantley -n 1 --exclusive mpirun --mca mtl psm" for which I have problem to include --bind-to none

The salloc man page can be found at https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/salloc.1.html ...

I just found from https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html  that I can  use --cpu-bind=no. But when I include this into "salloc salloc -p compute-grantley -n 1 --exclusive mpirun --mca mtl psm --cpu-bind=no ./test", I got the error mpirun: Error: unknown option "--cpu-bind=no"

please describe the issue you are facing when passing --bind-to none. also, try -N 1 instead of -n 1

Thanks. I have tried to use the command:  salloc -p compute-grantley -N 1 --exclusive --cpu-bind=no mpirun --mca mtl psm  ./test   But I always got the message "salloc: unrecognized option '--cpu-bind=no' "   Without --cpu-bind=no, I do not see the error message, but then I do not get any scaling with number of threads..  On my desktop, when I try " mpirun --bind-to none -np 1 ./test " I could see the scaling up to certain number of threads I open.

what is wrong with salloc -N 1 --exclusive mpirun -np 1 --mca mtl psm --bind-to none ./test? note you can also run in singleton mode: salloc -N 1 --exclusive ./test

It starts to scale now using your command with some small changes:  salloc --exclusive mpirun -n 1 --mca mtl psm --bind-to none ./test.   The cost is: 1 thread 0.04, 2 threads 0.02, 4 threads 0.016, 6 threads 0.0098. This is quite satisfying.  Still what is the difference between -n 1  and -np 1?  If I want to test the scaling on  two cores with varying threads for each core on the cluster, would it be right to run `alloc --exclusive mpirun -n 2 --mca mtl psm --bind-to none ./test.

@GillesGouaillardet Now I try to run on two cores with multiple threads. The costs are: 1 threads 0.02, 2 threads 0.01, 4 threads 0.0082, 6 threads 0.0047. All the times are half of the those using 1 cores.  They look quite promising.  Thanks

I do not understand your question. please use the right terminology: task/process, threads, node, core, hyperthread, ...

These terminologies are very confusing to me.  In the command salloc --exclusive mpirun -n 2 --mca mtl psm --bind-to none ./test  , can I understand that I asked for 2 cores for my mpi code,  and in the code I have called omp_set_num_threads(6)  that is binded to all 2 cores.  I am not sure how can I specify task/process in the command line using salloc.  Or shall I understand that it calls 2 tasks/processes and each task/process calls 6 number of threads.  I have no knowledge of hyperthread..
